# How to check for "island" vertices in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

So, I'm using a boolean operator to get the intersection of a bunch of pieces and a wall. Most pieces work fine but occasionally the intersection isn't perfect and you get these vertices that aren't connected to the rest of the mesh and this results in the mesh collider being incorrect, as seen in this [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mrJag.png).
My question is whether there is a way to detect these 'island' or 'lone' vertices.
I can provide additional images, code, or such if needed.

Thanks for any help! Ps. first question here so please be patient with me :)

Comment: Seems like a homework question to me. Share any research that you have already done for this problem and the things you have tried already.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and **the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself**. See: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Remove all zero area triangles, then remove vertices that are not in any triangle

Comment: @Ruzihm I understand I was a bit vague, but I was using a boolean operator I didn't write or understood so just accepted it would give me some incorrect pieces. I was looking for more of a hack-fix than anything.

Comment: @Balasubramanian It was a nice problem to learn from ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I kind of solved it by finding all connected vertices starting from a single vertex.

I started by picking the first triangle and adding it's vertices to a list of connected vertices. Then I go through the list of triangles comparing the position of their vertices to the list of connected vertices. If the triangle has a vertex with a position corresponding to a position in the list of connected vertices I add the entire triangle to the list. That's one iteration and I repeat this until all connected triangles are already in the list. If the connected triangle list is more than half of all triangles then I remove all other triangles, otherwise, I remove the current list of connected triangles. After that, I clear the vertices that aren't in a triangle like Leo Bartkus suggested.

It's extremely slow and it assumes there are only 2 separate islands or that you started on the biggest island, but it worked most of the time and was more for learning purposes anyways.

Thank's for the help!